# I got "ImportError: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing_extensions'" on snowflake.snowpark.session

Tags: session, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up Session for snowflake.snowpark.  I installed snowflake-connector-python 3.5.0 and typing_extensions 4.8.0.

But, When I set up Session ("from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session" ), I got the error message in , "ImportError: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing_extensions'". Could you help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks!!!

I am expecting no error message.

Comment: Installing Python connector only is not enough. Have you installed Snowpark as in `snowflake-snowpark-python` package?